# OpenGL, C++ Cornered Box

Tags: c++, opengl

I have been working on a GUI menu for a game (School project) we have like an engine template ready we just need to make a GUI menu. Me and my friend with teacher help have managed to make a non filled Box here is the function:

```
void BoxTest(float x, float y, float width, float height, float Width, Color color)
{
glLineWidth(3);
glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
glColor4f(0, 0, 0, 1);
glVertex2f(x, y);
glVertex2f(x, y + height);
glVertex2f(x + width, y + height);
glVertex2f(x + width, y);
glEnd();
glLineWidth(1);
glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
glColor4f(color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a);
glVertex2f(x, y);
glVertex2f(x, y + height);
glVertex2f(x + width, y + height);
glVertex2f(x + width, y);
glEnd();
}
```

This is how it looks like now:
http://gyazo.com/c9859e9a8e044e1981b3fe678f4fc9ab

The problem is I want it to look like this:
http://gyazo.com/0499dd8324d24d63a54225bd3f28463d

Becuse it looks so much better, but me and my friend has been sitting here for a couple of days with no clue on how to achive this.

Comment: Thank you, accidently linked wrong image fixed that!

Answer (score 2):

With OpenGL line primitives you'll have to break it down into multiple lines. GL_LINE_LOOP makes a a series of lines, connected with each other and closed at the end. Not what you want. Instead you should use simple GL_LINES. Every two glVertex calls (BTW: you shouldn't use those, because glVertex is terribly outdated; it's been out of fashion for almost 20 years) make one line.

Let's look at this ASCII art:

```
0 --- 1    4 --- 3
|                |
2                5

8                b
|                |
6 --- 7    a --- 9
```

You'd draw line segments

- 0 – 1
- 0 – 2
- 3 – 4
- 3 – 5
- 6 – 7
- 6 – 8
- 9 – a
- 9 – b

Replace the symbols 0…b with the coordinates of each point and you can make this

```
glBegin(GL_LINES);

glVertex( coords[0] );
glVertex( coords[1] );
glVertex( coords[0] );
glVertex( coords[2] );

glVertex( coords[3] );
glVertex( coords[4] );
glVertex( coords[3] );
glVertex( coords[5] );

glVertex( coords[6] );
glVertex( coords[7] );
glVertex( coords[6] );
glVertex( coords[8] );

glVertex( coords[9] );
glVertex( coords[0xa] );
glVertex( coords[9] );
glVertex( coords[0xb] );

glEnd();
```

As a final touch you can load the coords array into a OpenGL Vertex Array and use glDrawArrays or glDrawElements instead.